# want to know the name of tty_nr by range. Tty, ttyS, pts etc

Tags: operating-system, proc

I want to know the name of tty_nr by range like tty, ttyS, pts etc... I know it's divided according to the range of tty_nr. But I couldn't find the official document. Could you please refer to the official document link?

The tty_nr I'm talking about can be found in the proc/PID/stat file

I haven't found anything about this tty_nr range even though I've looked up man pages and gnu official documents.